# Primefaces selectManyMenu error on selecting many

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a interfaces uses selectManyMenu where dealer can select some criteria based on zip codes they service. They have almost 800 zip codes , if we select approx 250 it works but above that interfaces throws an error as below

```
<p:selectManyMenu  showCheckbox="true" style="width:100px;height:200px"     value="#{mergeList.lbean.selectedzips}">  
<f:selectItems value="#{mergeList.zips}" var="zp" itemLabel=" #{zp.name}" itemValue="#   {zp.name}" />  
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

> for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:441)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:71)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:115)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:134)
>   [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]  at
>   com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:123)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
>   [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]

Comment: you might have a typo here #mergeList.lbean.selectedzips} .. the opening bracket is missing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 List<ObjectName> selectedZips=new ArrayList<>();
 // getter & setter

<p:selectManyMenu  showCheckbox="true" style="width:100px;height:200px"
 value="#{mergeList.selectedzips}">  
<f:selectItems value="#{mergeList.zips}" var="zp" itemLabel=" #{zp.name}"
 itemValue="#{zp.name}" />  
 </p:selectManyMenu>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have it works well if you select around 250 zips and fails and throws the error if you select more